# Expressing $1-\exp{(\lambda_1p+\lambda_3q)}$ as $x+y$, where $x$ is in terms of $\lambda_1$ and $y$ is in terms of $\lambda_3$

Tags: exponential-function

I have this simple equation
$$c = 1 - \exp\left(\lambda_1 R^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) + \lambda_3 R^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$

I will like to express this in the form $c = x + y$, where $x$ is in terms of $\lambda_1$, and $y$ is in terms of $\lambda_3$. How can I go about this?

I have tried basic expansion. However, it seems that there might be a mathematical rule to get out of this.

Comment: Cannot be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$c(\lambda_1,\lambda_3)=1 - e^{(\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) + \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))}$$

Note first that $c(0,0)=1-e^0=0$.

Suppose we had the desired expression $c(\lambda_1,\lambda_3)=x(\lambda_1)+y(\lambda_3)$.  Then:

$$x(\lambda_1)+y(0)=c(\lambda_1,0)=1 - e^{\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) }$$

$$x(0)+y(\lambda_3)=c(0,\lambda_3)=1 - e^{ \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}$$

Adding the above, we get $$x(0)+y(0)+x(\lambda_1)+y(\lambda_3)=1 - e^{\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) }+1 - e^{ \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}$$
But also we have $$x(0)+y(0)+x(\lambda_1)+y(\lambda_3)=0+c(\lambda_1,\lambda_3)=1 - e^{(\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) + \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))}$$

Hence $$1+e^{(\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) + \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))}=e^{\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) }+e^{ \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}$$

Note that this can be written as $1+xy=x+y$, which can be rewritten as $0=xy-x-y+1=(x-1)(y-1)$ and therefore has solutions $x=1$ and $y=1$.  Hence, IF we can decompose $c=x+y$ as desired, then either $1=e^{\lambda_1 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) }$ or $1=e^{ \lambda_3 R^2 (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}$. In the first case, $\lambda_1=0$ (or $R=0$); in the second case, $\lambda_3=0$ (or $R=0$).  These can be all thought of as trivial.

If $R\lambda_1\lambda_3\neq 0$, then it is impossible to have a decomposition as desired.