# Expressing $c = 1 - \exp\left(\lambda_1 p + \lambda_3 q\right)$ as a product of two terms

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

This question is motivated by the response provided in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069885/expressing-1-exp-lambda-1p-lambda-3q-as-xy-where-x-is-in-terms-of)

Considering the same equation which is shown below
$$c = 1 - \exp\left(\lambda_1 R^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) + \lambda_3 R^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$

It has been proven that it cannot be expressed as a sum. Still, I am wondering if I can express this as a product like $c = x * y$, where $x$ is in terms of $\lambda_1$, and $y$ is in terms of $\lambda_3 $? I will appreciate insights on this matter.

Pardon, I am asking a similar question, but as you can see, the dimensions are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly as for the additive case, this is not possible unless $\lambda_1=0$ or $\lambda_3=0$ or $R=0$.

Suppose there exist two functions $x$ and $y$ such that
$$x(\lambda_1)y(\lambda_3)=1 - \exp\left(\lambda_1 p + \lambda_3 q\right)$$
Then note that $x(0)y(0)=1-1=0$.
Also
$$ x(\lambda_1)y(0)=1-e^{\lambda_1p}$$
$$ x(0)y(\lambda_3)=1-e^{\lambda_3q}$$
Multiplying the two yields
$$ x(\lambda_1)y(\lambda_3)x(0)y(0)=(1-e^{\lambda_1p})(1-e^{\lambda_3q})$$
But since $x(0)y(0)=0$, that means
$$(1-e^{\lambda_1p})(1-e^{\lambda_3q})=0$$
which implies that $\lambda_1=0$ or $\lambda_3=0$ or $R=0$.